# Как правильно отсортировать массив данных?

Tags: массивы, swift

Всем привет!

Выгружаю из Firebase Database данные в массив

```
var posts = [Post]()
```

После парсинга данных я добавляю все полученной в массив выше.
Вывожу в консоль - `print(self.posts)`

Вот что показывает -

```
[Port.Post(model: "test", 
           user: "User", 
           city: "Москва")]

[Port.Post(model: "test", 
           user: "User", 
           city: "Санкт-Петербург")]
```

Мне необходимо перебрать массив и оставить только часть, где значение `city:` будет равно `"Москва"`

То есть массив после сортировки будет -

```
  var SortedPosts = [Port.Post(model: "test", 
                         user: "User", 
                         city: "Москва")]
```

Как отсортировать так массив?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если я правильно понимаю что вы хотите получить, то это называется фильтрация а не сортировка. Решить ее можно через метод `filter`.

Пример:

```
struct Post {
  var model: String
  var user: String
  var city: String

  init(model: String, user: String, city: String) {
    self.model = model
    self.user = user
    self.city = city
  }
}


let post = Post(model: "test", user: "User", city: "Москва")
let post2 = Post(model: "test", user: "User", city: "Санкт-петербург")


var array = [post, post2]


array = array.filter { $0.city == "Москва" }
```